# How to hide blue button and label "My first Dataset" of PrimeFaces LineChartModel

Tags: jsf, primefaces, linechart

I need help solving something that neither ChatGPT nor BlackBox were able to figure out. I need to make that blue button disappear along with its label "My first Dataset". I tried to find the answer by reading almost everything on the official link https://www.primefaces.org/showcase-v8/ui/chartjs/line.xhtml, but unfortunately, I couldn't find the solution. Please save my soul!

Here is the method on my MB:

```
public void createComparativoDiaAnteriorLinhas() {
    this.lineModel = new LineChartModel();
    ChartData data = new ChartData();
    
    LineChartDataSet dataSet = new LineChartDataSet();
    List<Number> values = new ArrayList<>();
    values.add(65);
    values.add(59);
    values.add(80);
    values.add(81);
    values.add(56);
    values.add(55);
    values.add(40);
    dataSet.setData(values);
    dataSet.setFill(false);
    dataSet.setLabel("My First Dataset");
    dataSet.setBorderColor("rgb(75, 192, 192)");
    dataSet.setLineTension(0.1);
    data.addChartDataSet(dataSet);
    
    List<String> labels = new ArrayList<>();
    labels.add("January");
    labels.add("February");
    labels.add("March");
    labels.add("April");
    labels.add("May");
    labels.add("June");
    labels.add("July");
    data.setLabels(labels);
    
    //Options
    LineChartOptions options = new LineChartOptions();        
    Title title = new Title();
    title.setDisplay(true);
    title.setText("Line Chart");
    options.setTitle(title);
    
    lineModel.setOptions(options);
    lineModel.setData(data);
}
```

Bellow is the xhtml code:

```
<p:lineChart model="#{chartJsView.lineModel}" 
             style="width: 100%;
             height: 500px;"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That "blue button" and its label is the chart legend; you have to disable that legend. Using the code in [these docs](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/charts?id=linechart), somewhere after you have constructed a `LineChartOptions` instance that you'll be using to set options of the model, i.e., after

```java
   LineChartOptions options = new LineChartOptions();
```

and before

```java
    lineModel.setOptions(options);
```

you have to insert this:

```java
   Legend legend = new Legend();
   legend.setDisplay(false);
   options.setLegend(legend);
```